# Load UIWebview on app Lauch IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiwebview

I am attempting to create an application using the webview feature.

However, I need functionality that will allow me to segue between viewControllers without the webview taking time to present it self when the viewController loads.

This will require loading the webviews on the launch of the app. Any guidance on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the webView present in the first viewController when the app launches ?

Comment: No, its present after the launch screen is displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can create a singleton to hold the UIWebview. In your AppDelegate, you can initialize your singleton and load content of your UIWebview.
Everytime you want to use it, just get this view from the singleton and add it to whereever you want.

Comment: How do I create a singleton in my app delegate ? after researching what a singleton does its seems like a viable option.